# Trying to remember UK TV show about two dudes traveling through parallel universes

Tags: story-identification

The show had two main characters, one a stoner living with his grandma and the other guy is his best friend who's in an interracial relationship and about to get married (and is tired of the first guy's bullshit).

Some dude shows up with a sword in the first guy's house and tells him that he travels through parallel universes and kills this guy and his best friend. The guy with the sword dies and the stoner-dude and his best friend start traveling through universes.

I recall that the show had British characters and came out sometime after 2010

Comment: Cross-posted from http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/70681/9391 where it's off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like "[Tripped](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4699514/)"

> Best friends Milo and Danny embark on a series of bizarre adventures
>   across multiple, parallel universes.

For the record, Milo spends much of the first episode toking away furiously, even *after*
 the guy below turns up.

[image]

You can watch the trailer [here](http://www.channel4.com/programmes/tripped/videos/all/s1-trailer/4642358171001)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you actually know by heart everything you answer here? Or do you have some secret search engine? ;)

Comment: @DuaneDibbley - Stoners travel through time **movie** = Bill and Ted. Stoners travel through time TV show **(with British characters)** = Tripped. Stoners travel through time (**with American characters**) = Time Traveling Bong. It's not a hard find. The list is incredibly small.

Comment: By "here" I meant the site as a whole. You often answer story ident question with a fair amount of detail within just minutes, and you rarely get it wrong... And that is to be taken as a compliment, seasoned with a not so insignificant portion of envy.

Comment: @DuaneDibbley - It helps to watch a lot of TV :-)

Comment: @DuaneDibbley Also, Valorum has much more time on his hands now that he's lost his job after that pesky [Vote of No Confidence](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vote_of_No_Confidence)